# Tailwind CSS not applying Styles after Build

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

i have created Next Js Application with Tailwindcss everything is working fine in development environment but when I use npm run build command my tailwind CSS is not working its there in the code but CSS is not applying

Here is my code:

**_app.js**

```
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css";

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
};

export default MyApp;
```

**globals.css**

```
/* ./styles/globals.css */

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**tailwind config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  purge: ["./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: "#000000",
        Secondary: "#FFFFFF",
      },
      zIndex: {
        auto: "auto",
        negative: "-1",
        Secondary: "#FFFFFF",
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [postcss and autoprefixer](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs#install-tailwind-via-npm). Once installed, create a [postcss.config.js](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs#create-your-configuration-files) file in your root.

*postcss.config.js*

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    autoprefixer: {},
    tailwindcss: {},
  },
};
```